# Jquery Toggle & passing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have created a toggle button with jquery but I need to pass my `$id` so it can execute the mysql in `toggle_visibility.php`.

How do I pass my variable from my `<A>` tag ?

```
<a class="toggleVisibility">Yes</a>  
<script>
 $("a.toggleVisibility").toggle(
      function () {          
        $(this).html("No");          
      },

      function () {

      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "toggle_visibility.php",
       data: "id<?=$id; ?>",
       success: function(msg){
         alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
       }
     });

        $(this).html("Yes");
      }
    );

</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `$id` is a PHP variable so when the server generates your page it will be printed at the right spot.

But you are missing a `=` in the string:

```
data: "id=<?= $id ?>",
```

If this is not what you want you have to clarify where `$id` comes from.

**Update:**

You have to integreate the ID somehow in the table row. E.g. you could set is as `rel` attribute for the link:

```
<tr>
    <td class="date"><?php print $row['date']; ?></td>  
    <td><?php print $row['title']; ?></td>  
    <td class="visible">
        <a class="toggleVisibility" rel="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Toggle</a>
    </td>  
</tr>
```

then you can fetch it in the function with jQuery's `attr()` method:

```
$("a.toggleVisibility").toggle(
      function () {          
        $(this).html("No");          
      },
      function () {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "toggle_visibility.php",
            data: "id=" + $(this).attr('rel'),
            success: function(msg){
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            }
          });

          $(this).html("Yes");
     }
);
```

Comment: the id comes from the database, there are 10 rows and this $id needs to be passed from the <A> tag. The line was wrong but that is not the problem.

 <a class="toggleVisibility" href="?id=<?php print $id;?>">Yes</a>  

I would usually do it using $_GET like this, but how do I pass it to the jquery function?

thanks.

Comment: @Ross: Can you please show your HTML markup for the table? I assume you also show the ID in a cell. Basically you have to get the ID from there.

Comment: pasted below, it is a php while loop that output the rows of the table



<?php


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  ?>
  
     <tr>
     <td class="date"><?php print $row['date']; ?></td>
     <td><?php print $row['title']; ?></td>
     <td class="visible"><a class="toggleVisibility()" </a></td>
     <td class="modify"><a href="editnewsitem.php?id=<?php print $row['id']; ?>"><img src="img/modify_icon.gif" alt="modify" width="13" height="15" /></a>
     
     </td>
     </tr>

<?php
  
  }

?>